# Webpack 4 Rules to search and include component level SASS styles

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I have an Angular 6 SPA based on the template [here](https://github.com/damienbod/Angular2WebpackVisualStudio).

Now I have a couple of custom components with SCSS files relating only to the component themselves. These are located in the `/ClientApp` folder of the SPA.

The current rule on the SASS input in the `webpack.prod.js` is

```
const path = require('path');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpackTools = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
    .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const helpers = require('./webpack.helpers');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

console.log('@@@@@@@@@ USING PRODUCTION @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        polyfills: './ClientApp/polyfills.ts',
        vendor: './ClientApp/vendor.ts',
        app: './ClientApp/main-aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: ROOT + '/wwwroot/',
        filename: 'dist/[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'dist/[id].[hash].chunk.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],
        alias: rxPaths()
    },

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal',
        outputPath: path.join(ROOT, 'wwwroot/')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                use: '@ngtools/webpack',
                parser: {
                    system: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]',
                parser: {
                    system: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /favicon.ico$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=/[name].[ext]',
                parser: {
                    system: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                parser: {
                    system: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: path.join(ROOT, 'ClientApp/styles'),
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                parser: {
                    system: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: path.join(ROOT, 'ClientApp/styles'),
                use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'],
                parser: {
                    system: true
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'raw-loader',
                parser: {
                    system: true
                }
            }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    },
    plugins: [
        // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        //  analyzerMode: 'static',
        //  generateStatsFile: true
        // }),
        new webpackTools.AngularCompilerPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: './tsconfig-aot.json'
            // entryModule: './ClientApp/app/app.module#AppModule'
        }),

        // new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./wwwroot/dist', './wwwroot/assets'], {
            root: ROOT
        }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

        // new UglifyJSPlugin({
        //   parallel: 2
        // }),

        // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        //   name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
        // }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            template: './ClientApp/index.html',
            chunksSortMode: 'none' //fix for cyclic dependency
        }),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './ClientApp/images/*.*', to: 'assets/', flatten: true }
        ])
    ]
};
```

Which is obviously only loading the SASS files located in the `styles`. Is it possible to add some kind of recursive search on the app folder for additional SASS files? OR do I need to specifically import the styles.scss.

Comment: you need to specify imports. Otherwise webpack would not know about that asset. Webpack starts analysing from entrypoint to the leaf of the tree.

Comment: hmm ok, so for every component that has a specific .SASS file I need to import this manually to the styles.SCSS in the styles folder?

Comment: yes. Or you could import every single sass file on its equivalent component. A has a.sass. So on and so forth.

Comment: Ok so if they are imported in the component.ts then the file-loader should pull the style through correct? (I am doing this it just doesn't seem to be pulling the image links through and creating assets from them).

Comment: No, that is not the job for file-loader. Post your webpack config so we can analyse as well.

Comment: ok I thought it bundled all assets it found in the SASS files (like it does with fonts). I'll update to include my full webpack.config.js file

Comment: Why you have 2 rules for scss?

Answer (score 0):

The way that webpack acknowledges every single dependency is by analyzing your dependency tree, starting from your entry point(s). Webpack is only going to bundle/touch them if they are known dependencies, i.e:

`import {a} from 'b';
import 'styles.scss';
...`

To deal with assets, you have to provide a proper loader for each type of dependency. `file-loader` is usually used on images. The way that you declared is correct.

For css, you need (the order matters): `style-loader`, `css-loader`

For scss, you need (the order matters): `style-loader`, `css-loader`, `sass-loader`.

On your config, you have 2 rules for scss files, this might be the problem where it is using raw-loader (pure text).